# Accessibility: in what scenarios would aria-describedby not be announced?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am working on creating accessible help text for my form controls. I am planning to use `aria-describedby` to attach a accessible description to a field. This approach is discussed [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#using-aria-describedby)

Although in my testing with ChromeVox extension and Windows 10 screen reader I have found out that `aria-describedby` is not announced, [but it is rather well supported across browsers and screenreaders](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/), so i am planning to use this approach.

Also [this](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/09/describing-aria-describedby/) suggests that in some cases `aria-describedby` would be ignored or not work as expected but these cases are quite specific and i am generally ok with it.

> aria-describedby content may not always be announced to users,
>   depending on their screen reader and navigation method. The attribute
>   is well supported, but that doesn’t mean there aren’t some things to
>   be aware of: aria-describedby content may not be announced by all
>   screen readers if navigating to a button, link, or form control with
>   the virtual cursor. JAWS specifically may not announce an element’s
>   description when using hot keys to navigate to certain elements. When
>   navigating by visited links, the description will not be announced.
>   However JAWS should announce descriptions when navigating by form
>   controls. JAWS 17 + IE won’t announce aria-describedby content when
>   tabbing to a link (newer version of JAWS have fixed this). IE11 won’t
>   announce the accessible name or description of a form control if the
>   `title` attribute is used in tandem with aria-describedby, and the
>   user is navigating by virtual cursor or form control hot key (F). Both
>   will be announced if using the Tab key. (IE11 had much bigger problems
>   with aria-describedby in the past.) TalkBack + Android Chrome won’t
>   announce any aria-describedby content of a modal dialog when
>   auto-focusing an element within that dialog. If a user has
>   descriptions or hint text turned off, any associated content won’t be
>   announced. Because of this, it’s vital that any content that is
>   necessary to the understanding of a UI be available by means other
>   than just aria-describedby.

I would like to understand if there are times when `aria-describedby` would not be announced automatically? The previous link phrasing seems to suggest that it is only going to be announced on request :

> By using aria-describedby to reference the format of the field, this
>   information is made available to the users on request. That is, it is
>   not automatically displayed or read aloud. This makes sense if the
>   user has been informed of the format before, or when there are lots of
>   input fields with the same format, for example.

I don't get what it means by "on request". I believe that the default behavior is to announce the aria-describedby text after announcing the label and the input type.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `aria-describedby` (like `aria-label` and `aria-labeledby`) is profoundly influenced by the role of the element where they appear.

As you may know screenreaders generally have [two 'modes'](https://tink.uk/understanding-screen-reader-interaction-modes/), and this is mostly determined by the role (or default semantics) of the content.

I have certainly had problems getting non-interactive elements announced, if they appear within interactive ("forms mode") content.

I have had good results using `aria-describedby` with modal content. (Put the attribute on the modal, and point at the text elements inside which you want announced when the modal opens.) But I suppose this is because there is an obvious moment where the screenreader is supposed to make those announcements: the moment when the modal opens.

In the case that the form (or other "forms mode" container) is always present on the page, you can usually read the non-interactive content using browse-mode key combinations such as "next heading" ("H" on NVDA and JAWS) or "next paragraph" ("P"). Check to see if these 'requests' are enough of a solution.

You might also experiment with the standard HTML elements `fieldset` and `legend`, whose purpose is providing a text description for groups of interactive elements.

Also consider treating the 'form' (or toolbar or whatever) as a single tab stop, and use arrow keys to navigate the components within. This way, when you give focus to the container, you should get an announcement of whatever is `aria-describedby` (or indeed `aria-labeledby`/`aria-label`)

If this isn't working for you, there are a couple of hacks you might try as a last resort:

- Put `tabindex="-1"` on the element surrounding the text you want
  announced, and then call `focus()` on that element at the appropriate
  moment.
- Copy the text into the textContent of an `aria-live` region
  with javaScript at the appropriate moment.

Neither of these hacks are pretty, and might not suit you, if there is no 'appropriate moment'. (There's no equivalent of `onfocus` for browse mode). But with a little care, they can be made to work.

Comment: btw, while StackOverflow is a great resource, I would like to recommend the chatrooms of https://web-a11y.slack.com/ for discussion with battle-hardy accessibility heavyweights about nitty gritty aria/screenreader issues. It's a friendly and generous community.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info and the link to chatroom. 
1. you are suggesting that "on request" means that the screenreader user can ask to read the next heading or next paragraph.
2. I am using aria-describedby on a interactive form element, so i was kinda hoping that it would get announced by default without a "request"
3. I would expect it to be announced in "forms-mode", but based on your observation this might be the problem i am facing with ChromeVox.
4. on a separate note, is it actually a good idea to treat a form as a single tab stop instead of allowing regular tb navigation ?

Comment: 5. I understand fieldset and legend to group similar fields, i have just not seen it being used for help text. 

Thanks for all your input.

Comment: can you help me understand this with an example? 
I have certainly had problems getting non-interactive elements announced, if they appear within interactive ("forms mode") content.

Which non interactive elements were you expecting to be announced usually which weren't announced in "forms mode" ?

Comment: Problems may arise when you put things like (read-only) paragraphs and lists inside forms or modal dialogs. As you tab between the interactive elements, the non-interactive elements will be skipped. So if you want that content to somehow guide the user in operating the UI, then careful use of `aria-labelledby` and `aria-describedby` can achieve that.

Comment: I recognized the same problem as I added `aria-describedby` to a button. The additional information didn't appear in the VoiceOver rotor.

Comment: https://www.tpgi.com/the-current-state-of-modal-dialog-accessibility/ indicates that adding role=document to a modal helps VoiceOver to read non-operable content in certain situations