# ARIA-Description not being read by JAWS

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, accessibility, wai-aria

Maintaining an MVC 4 Razor legacy application and attempting to bind some text to a date input form. I want the date format to be described by a screen reader for accessibility purposes. Other advice online suggests [using this method](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/54/creating-accessible-input-forms-in-aspnet-mvc---section-508-compliance-and-ada-compliance), however I cannot seem to get it to work.

MVC Razor code:

```
@Html.LabeledDateTimeFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "date-dob", aria_describedby = "dob-format" })
<span id="dob-format"><strong>Format:</strong> mm/dd/yyyy</span>
```

HTML generated:

```html
<div class="editorfield">
    <input aria-required="true" aria-describedby="dob-format" class="date-dob date hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Birth Date must be a date." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="datetime" value="">
    <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" alt="Open Calendar">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
<span id="dob-format"><strong>Format:</strong> mm/dd/yyyy</span>
```

Edit: There is placeholder "**/**/____" that gets read by JAWS instead of the aria_describedby that I cannot override and I do not know where it is coming from.

Comment: If I run your generated HTML, JAWS announces the description. It says *"Edit Required, Format: mm/dd/yyyy, Type in text."*. Did you try testing just the generated code?

Comment: Yes I have, this is what is rendered to the client browser. See original post edit for more info

Answer (score 0):

From an accessibility perspective, knowing the date format would be useful to any user. You probably should render that on the client too with a `<label>` element.

```
<label for="expiry">Expiration date :
    <input type="text" name="expiry" id="expiry" aria-describedby="expDesc">
    <span id="expDesc">Format: mm/dd/yyyy</span>
</label>
```

I haven't used JAWS personally, but you can try `aria-labelledBy` to see if it's detected. Sometimes screen reader settings need to be tweaked.

According to the docs:
*The `aria-labelledby` property has the highest precedence when browsers calculate accessible names.*

This discussion may be relevant to note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56474712/13386355

Comment: I believe that is what the `Html.LabeledDateTimeFor` method is for. I've tried `aria-labelledby` as well with no luck. See edit to post